# How to get pHAT Stack to power multiple motor bonnets individually?

Tags: raspberry-pi4, adafruit, motordriver

We are working with a Raspberry Pi 4B and we are trying to power 6 different stepper motors with it. We have 3 different motor bonnets to drive 2 motors each and we bought the pHAT Stack to connect the 3 motor bonnets to the Raspberry Pi. We need each motor to be controlled individually but right now when we run our script all the motor bonnets do the same thing (i.e. if we control stepper1 on the code, all stepper1s do the same thing).

So our question is, how do we specify the address of each bonnet on the pHAT stack in order to power each motor individually? Or do the motor bonnets all use the same i2c address and the motors are not able to be controlled individually?

Any help would be amazing!

Here is an image of our setup without the power supply and with only 2 motor bonnets and 2 motors (1 in each bonnet as stepper1). For this example setup, how can we configure the address of each bonnet so that we can call it in our code to reference that bonnet when we want to control the motors it’s driving?
[image]

The list of parts we are using:
[Raspberry Pi 4 B](https://www.mcmaster.com/4284N26/)
[pHAT Stack](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/phat-stack?variant=658973392906) 
[Motor Bonnet](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4280)
[Stepper Motor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adafruit-industries-llc/4411/11497509)

We were expecting to be able to stack 3 different bonnets to be able to address each of them with a specific i2c address, but we might not be understanding the way i2c addresses work. We cannot initialize separate motorkits (we are using Adafruit's MotorKit library to drive the stepper motors) with different addresses on the pHAT stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you flip over the bonnet you'll see there a few address solder bridges that you can use to setup the stacked boards. Solder A0 for board #2 and A1 for board #3 and leave board #1.